# ClassNotFoundException while deserializing in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, serialization, weblogic12c

I have a webapp which saves state in the client side. State is accumulated into an `Object []`

```
Object state[] = new Object[10];

state[0] = _parent_s_state_array
state[1] = _some_int;
state[2] = _some_POJO;
..
..
```

then it is

- serialized
- Base64 encoded
- included as a hidden input in response

In next request this serialized state is submitted back and we reverse the steps to reconstruct state in serverside. This strategy is working fine for several hundred pages.

But for a certain page using a specific POJO with few String properties, I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` while deserialization. It is to be noted that object of the same class was created and serialized few moments ago in the same JVM session so we can rule out that Class not being present in classpath.

*Some more observations*

- This error is only seen in production and test platforms which is in **Weblogic 12c** and never seen in development where it is run in jetty 8 or 9. So I am guessing this is somehow related to Weblogic's class loading.
- This issue is consistently replicated in that specific page.
- There are other pages which uses same offending class without any problems in the same platform.
- The webapp is deployed from an exploded war directory and the class in question is present in `WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/yyy/`

Can somebody provide some pointers/strategy towards debugging this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Exception**

```
ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ClassNotFoundException occured restoring StateManager state from serialized form
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.yyy.TimeParameters
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap.doReadObject(AbstractHashedMap.java:1212) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
        at org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap.readObject(CaseInsensitiveMap.java:149) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
```

**Class**

```
package com.xxx.yyy;
public class TimeParameters implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5384703411813811209L;
    private String yr;
    private String qtr;
    private String mth;
    private String analysisType;

// Getters and Setters
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

A class from Apache Commons collections was involved somewhere during serialization. Since apache-commons-collections was loaded from Weblogic jars, it caused required class searched in Application classloader where it could not be found. Fix was to add `org.apache.commons.collections.*` to `prefer-application-packages` in `weblogic.xml`

**Details**

I did a remote debugger session to trace to a call to `Class.forName0(String className, boolean, ClassLoader loader)`.

Found that when the required class *could* be loaded, the classloader passed had a deeper hierarchy

```
this contains all classes in WEB-INF/classes --> weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@6437e3af finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@2cd01c0c annotation: mi.8200@MedicalIntelligence 
weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader@6413df9c finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@54bdae18 annotation: 
weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@5919d25d finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@1265cb83 annotation: 
java.net.URLClassLoader@5a88cbff
Application classloader, contains classes from weblogic bundled jars -->  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a9a42ef 
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@75a06ec2
```

And when it threw `ClassNotFoundException` it was cut short -- only last two entries were present

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a9a42ef <--   Hierarchy starts at Application classloader
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@75a06ec2
```

Then, I noticed that the stacktrace contained these lines ending with `~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]` (edited question to add more stacktrace)

```
    at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap.doReadObject(AbstractHashedMap.java:1212) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap.readObject(CaseInsensitiveMap.java:149) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
```

So Apache commons collections was being loaded from weblogic bundled jars ie `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a9a42ef` which might have triggered  *wrong* classloader to be passed further down the line. So added `org.apache.commons.collections.*` to `prefer-application-packages` in `weblogic.xml`

```
    <prefer-application-packages> 
        ...
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.collections.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
```

**Useful resources**

- Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT) provided by Weblogic: `http(s)://<server-hostname:port>/wls-cat`, shows Classloader tree
- [Understanding Classloading in Weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/classloading.html)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: How to resolve series](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html)

Comment: That would be my another idea.   I also ran more than once in weird issues  with weblogic classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

Java serialization is not the best way to accomplish your task.  You will be better off to serialize it into (say)  JSON and then compress it if you like.   Good choice would be google GSON.  Or XStream with JSON Driver.   Or Jackson ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant change that now. Besides this is working for several hundred pages